# facebook scraper sees different meta tags than source

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, share, meta

I'm trying to customize image, page title, and description data for facebook share feature on my page. When I view the og meta tags in the source of my page, I see the correct info

```
<meta property="og:title" itemprop="name" content="You got an A!" />
<meta property="og:description" itemprop="description" content="Find out how much you know about the Hittites at MYQUIZPAGE" />
<meta property="og:image" itemprop="image" content="http://PAGE/MYPAGE/MYIMAGE.jpg" />
```

However, when I plug the url into the facebook debugger, I instead see details of the parent site.

I dont know why this is, as the correct info is sent in the header, NOT appended afterwards or anything like that.

Im using the following anchor for the share button(wihch I have used many times in the past without fail)

```
<a href="//www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=MYURL" target="_blank">
```

One more detail- the content of the og tags on my page depends on values in the url query string.

Any ideas as to what is going on?